# Get sub string between some symbols

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

How to get string which is stored between some symbols?

So i have such string as `/some/path/to/project/HelloWorld.xcodeproj`. And i want to get result in variable as `HelloWorld`. Is it possible to do with shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this, for example:

Filename:

```
$ filename=$(basename /some/path/to/project/HelloWorld.xcodeproj)
$ echo $filename
HelloWorld.xcodeproj
```

Without extension:

```
$ echo ${filename%.*}
HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible:

```
$ NAME=/some/path/to/project/HelloWorld.xcodeproj
$ basename $NAME | cut -d. -f1       
HelloWorld
```

or if you always know the extension:

```
$ basename "$(basename "$NAME")" .xcodeproj
```

More universal solution (which also take into account a case from @fedorqui):

```
$ basename $NAME | sed 's|\.[[:alpha:]]\+$||'
```

And yet another solutuion (with more pipes but without regular expressions):

```
$ basename myfile.test.txt | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev
$ myfile.test
```

Comment: Mmm what if the file is `myfile.test.txt`? It would just return `myfile`. I know it is not the sample input, but could happen.